# CSS and scroll performance

Tags: css, performance, google-chrome-devtools

I have a tree-like HTML structure consisting of ~1k elements.
Page scrolling is accompanied by a low FPS.
Performance test shows frequent `Update Layer Tree`, which is takes 60% of the time.
[image]
[image]

I suspect that the reason lies in the CSS: disabled javascript doesn't change anything, but removal of all styles fixes the problem.

So, which CSS-properties or selectors can cause it?

Comment: Try to set `pointer-events: none` on all element while scrolling - see this [article](https://www.thecssninja.com/css/pointer-events-60fps).

Comment: @OriDrori I've already tried and it doesn't help

Comment: Play with `overflow` and [containment](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/06/css-containment) properties.

Comment: @wOxxOm What should be done with this `overflow` property? Set some specific value?

Comment: Can you send me a link to the page privately? I'm researching how to cover stuff like this better in the official DevTools docs. A direct message to [@kaycebasques](https://twitter.com/kaycebasques) works for me. Anybody else encountering stuff like this is welcome to message me, too.

Comment: @KayceBasques thanks for help. Your twitter messages is blocked from those you are not subscribed to. How can I write to you?

Comment: @legotin ah, I didn't think of that... in that case... email me at `kaycebasques@gmail.com`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if any particular CSS rule can cause such behavior. I would have to see the page to inspect it. Nevertheless, a proven technique for making large lists scroll more smoothly is to add `transform: translate3d(...)` to the list (at least for my company it proved its value). The below snippet gives an example. Maybe this can solve your problem to a degree.

```js
function createList (id) {
  const container = document.getElementById(id);
  
  for (let i = 0; i < 1e5; i++) {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.textContent = i;
    container.appendChild(div);
  }
}

createList('container-1');
createList('container-2');
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row no-wrap;
}

section {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#container-1 {
  background: red;
}

#container-2 {
  background: green;
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

```html
<section id="container-1"></section>
<section id="container-2"></section>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What's the point to use `display` and `flex-flow` properties for `body`?

Comment: @legotin I just wanted to display the examples next to each other. Could have used float instead. The only thing of importance, however, is the `transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)`. This 'trick' is quiet old actually, for example see http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/increase-your-sites-performance-with-hardware-accelerated-css

Comment: Still, it doesn't help(

Comment: @legotin Did you apply it to the element which actually scrolls?

Comment: Yes, I tried to apply it to the parent container as well as to items.
Generally speaking, I know this method, used it some times.
This is not a panacea, but it sometimes helps. But not this time.

Comment: Works for me, but why? In fact, only the z-axis is needed, so `transform: translateZ(0);` suffices. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/agc6sobn/